# sIFR links deactivate

Tags: wordpress, sifr, hyperlink

I am developing a Wordpress site using the WP sIFR plugin. Yesterday my hyperlinks suddenly stopped working after 15 minutes or so. When I open the page in a new window, they are reactivated, even in the original page. I am using Firefox 3 on a Mac.

http://stellaandmoon.com.au/art/

Can anyone help me? I would really appreciate any suggestions :)

Cheers,

Julia

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `wmode` value from the Flash movies.